# Py.test mixin class can't access `self`

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to make a mixin for a shared set of tests. I want to be able to inherit from the mixin whenever I want those generic tests to run.

Here is some of my mixin:

```
class CommonRuleWhenTestsMixin(TestCase):

    def test_returns_false_if_rule_inactive(self):
        self.rule.active = False

        assert not self.rule.when(self.sim)
```

Here is when I use the mixin:

```
class TestWhen(CommonRuleWhenTestsMixin):

        def setUp(self):
            self.customer = mommy.make(Customer)
            self.rule = mommy.make(
                UsageRule,
                customer=self.customer,
                max_recharges_per_month=2
            )
            self.sim = mommy.make(
                Sim,
                msisdn='0821234567',
                customer=self.customer
            )

            assert self.rule.when(self.sim)

        def test_returns_false_if_airtime_max_recharges_exceeded(self):
            self.rule.recharge_type = AIRTIME
            mommy.make(
                SimRechargeHistory,
                sim=self.sim,
                product_type=AIRTIME,
                _quantity=3
            )

            assert not self.rule.when(self.sim)
```

I keep getting this message:

```
_________ CommonRuleWhenTestsMixin.test_returns_false_if_rule_inactive _________                                                                                                                                  
simcontrol/rules/tests/test_models.py:14: in test_returns_false_if_rule_inactive                                                                                                                                  
    self.rule.active = False                                                                                                                                                                                      
E   AttributeError: 'CommonRuleWhenTestsMixin' object has no attribute 'rule'
```

How can my mixin access the variables set on `self` by the child class?

Comment: Is TestCase here the one from unittest? Are you sure `setUp` is being run?

Comment: Yes, and yes, as I asserted False in the setup to check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mixin inerhits from `unittest.TestCase`, so its test gets picked up by pytest (and would probably get picked up by `unittest` as well).

Instead, don't inherit your mixin from anything (or from `object` on Python 2), and make your `TestWhen` class inherit from both `unittest.TestCase` and `CommonRuleWhenTestsMixin`.